# 入力された値の商が0.000001以下になるまで割り算

Tags: javascript, アルゴリズム

javaScript勉強中です。超初心者です。よろしくお願いいたします。

もし入力された数字が2から10の間の時、その入力された数字の商が0.000001以下になるまで2で割り続け、小数第6位以下(0.000001)に到達するまで何回割ったかというコードを書いています。例えば7/2を小数第6位まで割り切るのに23回割り算しました。という結果が欲しいです。

以下が自分のコードです。
このコードが間違っているのはわかっています。まだ途中です。わからないところは：

1. while文での初期値:　2と10の間のどれかの数字から始まる
2. 条件は0,000001以下なのか、以上なのか
3. 入力された数字を2で割った答えが次の分母になるわけですが、そうなるとInputNum++ではない？
4. もしくは小数点以下の桁数を数える方法の方がいいのか

ご教授お願いいたします。

```
if (InputNum <= 1 ||  InputNum >= 11) {
    alert( 'Please enter an invalid number.' );

    let InputNum = (InputNum > 1 && InputNum < 11)
    while (InputNum > 0.000001){
    InputNum = InputNum / 2
    alert( InputNum )
    InputNum++
```

Comment: 「1億桁に行く」とはどのような概念でしょうか？

Comment: わかりにくい説明ですみません。編集いたしました。小数第６位とゆうことです。

Comment: @K0982347 サンプルのIF条件だと「1以下か、11以上の場合」になるので2〜10以外の場合のみ処理されてますね

Comment: @Myaku あ。本当ですね、不等式がとても苦手で。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

数学を勉強すべきです。[`log2`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/log2)と[`ceil`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/ceil)で求めることができます。

```
const count = Math.ceil(Math.log2(InputNum / 0.000001));
```

`InputNum = 7`であれば`count = 23`になります。

Comment: なるほど。数学勉強します。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1):

回数を数えるなら専用のカウンタ変数を作りましょう
カウント以外で値が変更されてしまう変数は使わないことと
ループに比較する値がいつまでもインクリメントされ、指定以下にならないので無限ループします。

```js
function startDivide(){
  //値取得
  var inputNum = document.getElementById("val").value;
  //数値チェック
  if(""==inputNum || !isFinite(inputNum)){ console.log("not numeric"); }
  //数値が2〜10の場合のみ処理
  if( 2 <= inputNum && 10 >= inputNum ){
    //入力値を壊すのも何なので一旦別に保存
    var nowDivide = inputNum;
    //割ったカウントをする変数
    var counter = 0;
    //0.000001を現在値が超えている場合のみループ
    //while( 0.000001 < nowDivide ){ 処理 }
    
    //なんだけど、小数点第６位に到達するまでを数えるならこうじゃないかな？
    //小数点第５位以上の場合のみループ
    while( 0.00001 <= nowDivide){
      //2で割って再格納
      nowDivide /= 2;
      //counterをインクリメントしてからコンソールに表示
      console.log(++counter);
    }
    //結果表示
    console.log("結果："+nowDivide);
    console.log("到達まで、"+counter+"回割った");
  }else{
    //対象外のベース値
    console.log("invalid value");
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="val" value="" placeholder="割られる値（半角数値のみ）" /><button onclick="startDivide()">割り算開始</button>
```

Comment: 大変勉強になります。ありがとうございました。